# How to add a specific value of maxWidth option in Resizable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resizable

http://jsfiddle.net/ndpnU/2/

I want to set the maxWidth but I can't find any solution, can ypu please help me?

I use this:

```
$("#one").resizable({
    minWidth: 200,
    handles: 'e',
    maxWidth: $(this).next().width() - 200 + $(this).width(),
    alsoResizeReverse: "#two",

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `maxWidth` property of the resizable is indeed being set, just not to the value that you are expecting.  When I load the page in my browser, `maxWidth` is being set to about 1200.  That is because `$(this).next().width()` returns null and `$(this).width()` probably isn't returning the value you're expecting it to.

It appears that you're assuming `this` refers to the `#one` element.  However, in your code, `this` actually refers to the `#document` element.  Thus $(this).next() returns null because `#document` has no sibling elements.  You can verify this by using the JS debugging/developer tools in your browser.

Perhaps instead of `#document`, you really want to use the `#one` element.  In that case, you could fix your code as follows:

```
var $oneEl = $("#one");
$oneEl.resizable({
    minWidth: 200,
    handles: 'e',
    maxWidth: $oneEl.next().width() - 200 + $oneEl.width(),
    alsoResizeReverse: "#two",
});
```

Comment: If this is correct I'd appreciate if you would select my answer.  If this didn't work, let me know also so we can figure it out.